# Use SystemSettings 1.0?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, qt5

I'm developing a new app that I need to use the SystemSettings module for (I need to get the device serial, IMEI and stuff). When looking for a way to get these numbers I came across Ubuntu System Settings (for the mobile device) which uses this module and shows both serial and IMEI.

When I added the SystemSettings 1.0 module and submodules they are not installed on my computer. So I tried running it on a device, because they should be installed there, since the system settings app shows these numbers, right? Wrong. It does not work.

So my question is: How do I install and use the SystemSettings module used here: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~system-settings-touch/ubuntu-system-settings/trunk/view/head:/plugins/about/PageComponent.qml

Thanks in advance,
Cheers
Daniel